# How to log stored procedure calls in application logs

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server 2008 as database and using mssql-jdbc driver for connectivity. I want to know if there is a way to log every stored procedure call with input parameters in the application logs? While debugging any function in my application sometime it takes lot of time for me to debug what all stored procedures were called from my application and what were the parameters.

Comment: Why not just use SQL Profiler?

Comment: I am not sure if I am clear in my question, but what I want is not to log these details in database but in application server in my application log files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) for your custom logging, but you must rewrite your function calls, otherwise you can use the [Extended Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354(v=sql.105).aspx) or Profiler on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This would mean changing every single procedure in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am not looking for logging this information in SQL server log file, but actually I would like to log it in my JAVA application log file.